# "Might" In Second Conditionals?

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this sentence, please:

1) You ***might*** say that work is coming back into fashion.

Can I convert 1) into a second conditional sentence? For example:

1a) (If you ***wanted*** to), you ***might*** say that work is coming back into fashion.    **Or**

1b) (If you ***were*** to give your opinion on this), you ***might*** say that work is coming back into fashion.

I know ***could*** is possible in 1a) and 1b). But, here I'm talking about ***might*** *only*.

Can I use ***would possibly*** in place of ***might*** in 1a) and 1b), too?

Comment: I think you will get better answers at ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your use of modals in 1a and 1b sound fine to my AmE ears. And in the South, one can use double modals, as in "I might could go to the ball game with y'all."

Comment: They are both fine in British English too, (although double modals are simply wrong.)